# cursor predeterminado campo php

Tags: php, mysql

tengo este formulario en php conectado a una informacion en mysql

> $contents[] = array('text' => '
> descripcion
> ' .
>   tep_draw_input_field('descripcion', $mInfo->descripcion));
>   $contents[] = array('text' => '
> Cantidad
> ' .
>   tep_draw_input_field('cantidad', $mInfo->cantidad));

necesito que cuando entre en esta pagina el cursor este posicionado en el campo ***cantidad*** del formulario., listo para escribir 
[image: campo cantidad debe estar el cursor]

como o que comando utilizar para que apenas entre a la web el cursor este en ese campo y no hacer clic para escribir en el

he intentado ahcer esto pero no funciona:

> $contents[] = array('text' => '
> Cantidad: 
> ' .
>   tep_draw_input_field('cantidad', Null, 'autofocus'));

Puedo hacerlo con GET? como se llama la funcion que tengo que insertar en el link?

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer con el atributo **autofocus** de html5.

```
<input type="text" autofocus >
```

Comment: pero en esta linea como se inserta: $contents[] = array('text' => '<br />Cantidad:xxx <br /><input type="text" autofocus >' . tep_draw_input_field('cantidad'));

Answer (score 1):

con esto si funciono gracias por recordarme el comando autofocus

> $contents[] = array('text' => '
> Cantidad: 
> ' .
>   tep_draw_input_field('cantidad', NULL, 'required
>   autofocus="autofocus"'));